# Net::http and HTTParty work locally but not on Heroku - RoR3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, httparty, net-http

I am working on some RoR3 app and I have to make a HTTP request to some server.

I tried Ruby's **Net::HTTP** lib and is working locally but not on Heroku. I then tried **HTTParty** and get it to work locally but it still doesn't work on Heroku. I get

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

When I check the Heroku logs I get

> 500 Internal server error

showing as the last log.

I made sure the 'httparty' gem is mentioned in the right place in gemfile.

Is there any tutorial on how to make a HTTP request from Heroku PaaS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amit Suroliya was correct. I was using HTTParty as well and it was working through Curl and Development but would crash in production. Because the HTTParty parameter is the literal URL(as a string), it has to be a flawless URL/URI (meaning no spaces). My bad URI was as follows:

```
HTTParty.get("http://api.blahblahblah.com/v1/Boards/Search?&limit=79&query=#{query}&filter_date_from=1423353600")
```

Notice the interpolation `query=#{query}"`, So if `query='Michelle Obama'`, notice space between `Michelle` and `Obama`. Because of interpolation, the `HTTParty.get('string')` it is incorrect.

SOLUTION:

Replace all whitespaces within your string with `+`, or you could use `%20`.

I used `query.gsub!(' ', '+')`

For more info on whitespace in the URL check it out here: Spaces in URLs?